# TypeScript Array<>.reduce() Types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Is there a way within TypeScript to change the type expected to be returned by an `Array.reduce` call from the type given to it?  The code I'm having an issue with is below for the sake of an example:

```
let executionSequence: RelationalReversionQuery[][] = this.reduce(
    (accumulator: RelationalReversionQuery|RelationalReversionQuery[][], item: RelationalReversionQuery) => {
    if (accumulator instanceof RelationalReversionQuery) {
        if ((accumulator.ExecutionSequence === RelationalReversionQueryExecutionSequence.Indifferent) && (item.ExecutionSequence === RelationalReversionQueryExecutionSequence.Indifferent)) {
            return [[accumulator, item]]
        }
        return [[accumulator], [item]];
    }
    if (item.ExecutionSequence !== RelationalReversionQueryExecutionSequence.Indifferent) {
        accumulator.push([item]);
        return accumulator;
    }
    if (accumulator.length > 0) {
        let lastArray = accumulator[accumulator.length - 1];
        if (lastArray.length > 0) {
            if (lastArray[lastArray.length - 1].ExecutionSequence === RelationalReversionQueryExecutionSequence.Indifferent) {
                lastArray.push(item);
            } else {
                accumulator.push([item]);
            }
        } else {
            lastArray.push(item);
        }
    } else {
        accumulator.push([item]);
    }
    return accumulator;
});
```

`this` is extending the type `Array<RelationalReversionQuery>`.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What do you expect happens and what happens instead?

Comment: @VLAZ Code-wise it works without the type issues in JavaScript, but in TypeScript I'm getting type errors in WebStorm.  I'm expecting to take in an `Array<RelationalReversionQuery>` and output an `Array<Array<RelationalReversionQuery>>` - that is, there's a type change which occurs within the accumulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is interesting. The built-in type doesn't allow you to return a different type of the original type unless you specify the 2nd argument of `.reduce` function in this case.

```
this.reduce((accumulator: RelationalReversionQuery|RelationalReversionQuery[][], item: RelationalReversionQuery) => {
  // ...
}, []);

//  ^ this is what you need to add
```