# Insert item between every other item in array similar to Array.join

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript

`Array.join` is useful because it glues together an array of strings by a delimiter  taking into account empty arrays and not padding the delimiter at either end of the output string.

I am making a React application and I would like find a similar native function, however, my array of `React.ReactNode` elements is going to be mapped and rendered, so instead of joining the array with a delimiter and outputting a string, I just want to join the array with a string delimiter, but maintain the Array structure. Is there something already native to javascript/typescript/react that I can use to achieve the below psuedo-code?

```
let parts: React.ReactNode[] = [];
if (conditionA) {
  parts.push(<div>Component One</div>);
}
if (conditionB) {
  parts.push(<div>Component Two</div>);
}
parts = joinByDelimiterButKeepAsArray(parts, '|');
// I wants parts to now equal
// [<div>Component One</div>, '|', <div>Component Two</div>]
// if conditionA and conditionB are both true
return (
  <>
    {parts.map((part, i) => return (
      <React.ReactFragment key={i}>{part}</React.ReactFragment>
    ))}
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, kind of answered my own question. Currently, I use the following function to achieve this:

```
function joinByDelimiterButKeepAsArray<T>(a: T[], delimiter: T): T[] {
  return a.flatMap((n, i) => (i + 1 < a.length ? [n, delimiter] : [n]));
}
```

Example:

```
const parts: React.ReactNode[] = [];
parts.push(<div>Component One</div>);
console.log(joinByDelimiterButKeepAsArray(parts, '|'));
/// [{...}]
parts.push(<div>Component Two</div>);
console.log(joinByDelimiterButKeepAsArray(parts, '|'));
/// [{...}, '|', {...}]
parts.push(<div>Component Three</div>);
console.log(joinByDelimiterButKeepAsArray(parts, '|'));
/// [{...}, '|', {...}, '|', {...}]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `reduce` without the *initialValue* argument:

```
a.reduce((acc, val) => [].concat(acc, delimiter, val));
```

This requires special care when `a` is an empty array. If that needs to be supported, then:

```
a.length ? a.reduce((acc, val) => [].concat(acc, delimiter, val)) : a;
```

#### Addendum

I just [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69445281/typescript-array-reduce-types) that TypeScript only allows the second argument of `reduce` to be omitted when `reduce` will return the same type as the array elements. Here we want to return a different type (`T[]` instead of `T`), yet start out with an implicit `T` initial value. Not possible.

So this restriction kills the beauty of the above JavaScript solution, as now we have to provide the second argument:

```
a.reduce<T[]>((acc, val) => acc.concat(delimiter, val), []).slice(1);
```

And with additional type specifications for the callback parameters:

```
a.reduce<T[]>((acc: T[], val: T) => acc.concat(delimiter, val), []).slice(1);
```

Comment: Could you provide a typed solution for this?

Comment: Good remark... Turns out that TypeScript needs more. See addition to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this solution:

```js
const parts = ['<div>Component One</div>', '<div>Component Two</div>'];

/**
 * Add the delimiter between each item in the array.
 *
 * @param {any[]} array
 * @param {string} delimiter
 * @returns {any[]}
 */
const joinByDelimiterButKeepAsArray = (array, delimiter) => {
  /**
   * To prevent the function from crashing, we need to check if the array is an array.
   */
  if (!Array.isArray(array) || array.length === 0) {
    return [];
  }

  const [firstElement, ...rest] = array;

  return rest.reduce((acc, curr) =>
    acc.concat(delimiter, curr)
    /**
     * The initialValue is set to an array containing the first element of the array to
     * prevent the edge case of an array of length 1. If we don't do this, it would result
     * in an array of length 2 with the first element being the first element of the array
     * and the second element being the delimiter.
     *
     * e.g. [onlyOneElement] -> [onlyOneElement, delimiter]
     */
  , [firstElement]);
};

console.log(joinByDelimiterButKeepAsArray(parts, '|'));
```

### UPDATE

I've never used Typescript before. The typing would probably look like this:

```
const joinByDelimiterButKeepAsArray: <T>(array: T[], delimiter: T) => T[] = (array: T[], delimiter: T): T[] => {
  if (!Array.isArray(array) || array.length === 0) {
    return [];
  }

  const [firstElement, ...rest] = array;

  return rest.reduce((acc: T[], curr: any): T[] =>
    acc.concat(delimiter, curr)
  , [firstElement]);
};
```

Please consider marking this as an answer if it helped!

Comment: could provide a typed solution for this?

Comment: Please see the updated answer for the requested changes.